# Unable to test HOC containing hooks using React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-functions, react-testing-library

Below is the code for HOC

```
const HOC = ({ component: Component }) => {
  return () => {
     const id = useQuery(query);
     return (<div> 
         {!id ? ( <SomeOtherComponent prop1={'hello'} prop2={'world'} /> ) : ( <Component /> )}
     </div>)
  }
}
```

Below is the test to render HOC-

```
const myComponent = () => <div data-testid={'component-testid'}>ABC</div>;
    const renderHOC = HOC({component: myComponent})();
    const {getByTestId} = render(renderHOC);
    expect(getByTestId('component-testid')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Getting the error-
Invalid hook call. React hooks must be called inside react functional component.

Comment: Right now there are no hooks in your code. What is `Component` and `SomeOtherComponent` respectively? Are they the same?

Comment: useQuery() is the hook. These are two separate component.The HOC is working perfectly on UI , however i am unable to write the test for same.

Comment: Ah! Then you should be able to fix this by moving `const id = useQuery(query);` out of the `return () => {...}` statement.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as follows

```
const RenderHOC = HOC({component: myComponent});
const { getByTestId } = render(<RenderHOC />);
```

You cant call a component as a function if it contains hooks.